# Could webassembly be a way to enforce drm?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, drm, webassembly

The Idea of using compiled languages on might be a great way to increase performance significantly.

But could it used to set a drm?

For example: Some website offers browser games and doesn't want the source code to be used by others. Would webassembly-script tied deep into the game mechanics be used to detect if it is used on another site and lock it down with no way to decompile and bypass it?

I don't want to sound like a pirate with this, but it might concern adblock-users, that [also block trackers](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock).

When for example a [Audio Context Fingerprinting](https://audiofingerprint.openwpm.com/)-script is run behind without being detected, how can it be blocked?

Comment: Great question! The promise of WASM + DRM could be that copyright holders can control what can be done with their content, but it would allow one to create fully open source browsers that support all DRM even if the copyright holders are too lazy to support them, as long as these browsers support WASM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than performance, Wasm does not provide any new capability that the Web doesn't already have. You will be able to see what Wasm modules are loaded, you will be able to see what's being called, and you can inspect and step through Wasm code in text form -- and arguably, Wasm code is no more obscure than e.g. minified asm.js code. Moreover, Wasm is only able to interact with the browser and the web page by calling into JavaScript.

So, no, web sites won't be able to use it to do anything behind your back other than in ways they can use already.

Comment: I don't understand... I think you're saying that because one can "inspect and step through Wasm code in text form" it isn't suitable for DRM. But can't one "inspect and step through any DRM code in text form" with e.g. GDB and see the machine instructions in symbolic form? How does compiled C -> binary library provide "better" DRM protection than C -> WASM?

Comment: "other than performance"... But performance is key! Obscured Javascript would not in general be able to decrypt live HiRes video on a Raspberry PI, but WASM might over time...

Comment: asm.js is JS that's no less obscure than Wasm and also delivers near-native perf. There is a quantitative difference between what both languages can do, but it's way too small to be a qualitative one for the purpose in question. Any DRM technique you could apply to Wasm you could also apply to JS.